# How to delete user from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am a new PHP programmer. I created a user login page where can i see list of user who is logged in. I am using PDO for connecting database. The Problem is if I want to delete user from the list it only delete the last inserted user. What i am doing wrong ? Can someone please help me...

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $time = $row['time_out'];
        echo "
        <input type='text' value='$row[user_name]' name='user_name'>
        <input type='text' value=' $row[course]' name='course'>
        <input type='text' value=' $time'>
        <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
        <br>";
    }
    ?>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //get course
    $course = $_POST['course'];

    //get user_name
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];

    //deleting user from the database
    $database->delete($user_name);

    //Redirect to current page
    header('Location: tutor.php');
    exit;
}
```

Here is my method for getting logged in user:

```
public function selectFromOnline()
    {
        $sql = $this->connection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM online");
        $sql->execute();
        return $sql->fetchAll();
    }
```

Here is my method for deleting user:

```
public function delete($user_name)
    {
        $sql = $this->connection()->prepare("DELETE FROM online WHERE user_name = :user_name");
        $sql->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql->execute();
        return $sql;
    }
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. You do not describe what your problem is. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: Look at the HTML you're generating. Each user has a hidden field called user_name; and your code will only ever be passed a single parameter called user_name, which will be the final one set - when you have two fields with the same name, earlier ones are over-written by later ones.

Comment: As a quick fix, try enclosing the <form> tags inside the for loop, so each user is its own form, so there won't be any fields to be over-written. Alternatively, look at ways you could keep everything in a single form, but rename the field so each user's details all have  unique names in the form.

Comment: @andrewsi: Nice idea, I might also add that you can add get variables to the action, so that the correct user may be identified. (`action="?user=$user_id"`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every input has the same name so you get nothing when you try to obtain POST values. Try a different approach. Maybe you can add a new field (hyperlink) that performs the redirect action and send the parameters of deleting action with GET.

Example:

```
echo "
    <input type='text' value='$row[user_name]' name='user_name'>
    <input type='text' value=' $row[course]' name='course'>
    <input type='text' value=' $time'>
    <a href='Test.php?username=$row[user_name]&course=$row[course]'>delete</a>        
    <br>";
```

}

Test.php is the name of your php page.
Then you can query the database by using the the GET value:

```
$_GET["username"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry But I didn't understand your code but I understood your problem and here it is my solution with "mysqli_query"....

```
<?php
//Please set these veriables according to your values....
$host_name = "YOUR_DB_HOST_NAME";        //Normally 'localhost'
$password = "YOUR_PASSWORD_FOR_MYSQL";   //your password
$username = "YOUR_USERNAME_FOR_MYSQL";   //Normally Root
$database_name = "NAME_OF_YOUR_DATABASE";
$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $username, $password, $database_name);
if(!$connect){
  echo "Something is Wrong Please Check your host name, user name, password or     database name";
}
?>

<!--YOUR FORM STARTS----------------------------------------------------->
<!--DON'T FORGET TO SET ACTION TO #(ON THE SAME             PAGE)------------------------------------>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <?php
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $time = $row['time_out'];
        //Any Two Input Fields Cant have same Name So...
        echo "
        <input type='text' value='$row[user_name]' name='user_name_display'>
        <input type='text' value=' $row[course]' name='course'>
        <input type='text' value=' $time'>
        <input type='hidden' value='$row[user_name]' name='user_name'>
        <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
        <br>";
    }
    ?>
</form>
<!--YOUR FORM ENDS----------------------------------------------------->

<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //get course
    $course = $_POST['course'];

    //get user_name
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];

//Creating and running mysqli query
$delete = "DELETE FROM online WHERE user_name='$user_name'";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $delete);

if($query){
  //Code to run when user is deleted
  header("Location: tutor.php")
}else{
  //Error to show when can't delete user
  echo "Sorry Can't delete the user";
}
}
?>
```

Just forget about some semicolons and some minor errors (if there is any), It'll Defiantly Work....
Please Don't Forget to Vote if it works....